# How make equal cuts regardless of orientation

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling the bridge of a spaceship and I want it to look as if it was engineered. How would I make sure all these cuts are equal? I just loop cut it and eyeballed it (3 on the front, 4 on the side) but I am also concerned about the diagonals. Is there any way to cut around a mesh in equal parts?

[image: example]

Comment: You could use Knife Cut with cut-through activated (I've used this to cut-and-separate models along equally-spaced cubes before, for example); if the non-diagonals are aligned with the y- and x-axes, this would give you everything but the diagonals, and it would give you enough vertices to form the diagonals by deleting faces/adding new faces back again.

Comment: Are you asking how to make equal diagonals (@JachymMichal) or all segments marked by yellow line?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Bevel modifier

1. Select the edges where you want the cuts
2. Add a *Mean Bevel Weight* through Sidebar
3. Add a *Bevel modifier*, Limit method > Weight

Then just apply the modifier (if you want) and add loopcuts manually.

[image]